# We should earn Steward without using the queue or we should be able to look more than 3 tags on filter

Tags: discussion, review, badges, vote-to-close

If we see a question that has a number on the close link, this indicates a problem with the question. **If we properly read the question and agree on this close reason** then we can immediately click close and select the same reason to increase the count. However, this doesn't increase the Steward count. One has to use the queues. If we don't agree, we don't vote.

Especially for Stack Overflow, this is a huge issue for earning this badge. I don't want to cast close votes for arbitrary questions, I want to cast close votes on the tags that I've been watching.

- We should earn by casting votes on the close link if there is already one. It will not differ in the case that it is already on my queue. Yes, it takes time to fall into the queue, however, we can ignore this if it is going to be in my queue.

Or,

- The review queues should allow having more than 3 tag filters or should enable us to use our filters so that we can easily look at those all at once.

Comment: Review queues do allow filtering by tags https://i.stack.imgur.com/spQLb.png, but I agree we should be allowed to earn the badge without the queues. I usually don't use queues much on InfoSec, but still cast close votes on posts as they come in.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, it allows only 3 tags. I've 10 on SO and like 10 on InfoSec, too. Still too less.

Comment: Seeing a number on a close link shouldn't be what tells you there is a problem, the content should.

Comment: @charlietfl Well, of course, I look at the content of the question, why should I vote close if I don't see a problem. Doesn't it happen the same way as in the queues? We see them since someone castes them. Do we simply agree without reading, no obviously?

Comment: Then I probably don't interpret your first sentence the way you intended it to mean. It reads like ..."I don't vote until someone else does"

Comment: Somewhat. What is the relevance of a close link having a number or not?

Comment: @charlietfl I think the relevance is that if a question has a number it means it will be in the CV review queue. So that means we are voting on a question that is in the review queue but not going towards the review badge.

Comment: If there is no number then it means that there is no vote cast. I'm casting many first-time votes on SO. It is the same as the queue where one can get steward,